Como generar private key para Firebase Cloud Messaging API V1?
Estoy intentando generar la private key para Firebase Cloud Messaging API V1. Por lo que estuve leyendo se trata de un JSON que se puede descargar. La idea es que ese JSON lo pueda utilizar un proveedor externo que brinda servicios de notificaciones push a través de un SDK.
La api de Firebase Cloud Messaging (V1) ya está habilitada:

Lo que tengo dudas, cuales son los pasos para generar el JSON con la private key? Estando la V1 habilitada, es necesario desactivar la API de Cloud Messaging (heredada)?

Las API heredadas dejarán de usarse en junio del 2024 según la documentación. En ese mismo enlace te explica cómo configurar el cliente según el entorno (panel de la izquierda).

Muchas gracias por el enlace, voy a revisar esa documentación.

En el panel de la izquierda aparecen los entornos: iOS+,Android, Aleteo, C++, Unity, etc. Debes revisar la documentación específica, según el entorno que quieras configurar. Ahí explica lo que puedes hacer y paso por paso cómo lo debes hacer.

Revisando la documentación encontré la respuesta, es muy sencillo. El archivo JSON se descarga directamente desde esta pestaña en la consola de Firebase:

Antes lo estaba descargando de la consola de Google Cloud, y por eso aparentemente no funcionaba.
